# I am not able to find 'script' package in atom text editor

Tags: atom-editor

I recently installed atom text editor and start using it. I want to use it mainly to run Python codes. for that, I am trying to install a few packages like 'script'. I am not able to find this package.

Comment: Atom's packages backend had some major troubles in the past couple of weeks, often responding with status code. You could install the package manually from [GitHub](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading it directly from the site and opening it with atom https://atom.io/packages/script

Answer (score 0):

Make "Atom" as Default atom:// Protocol Handler by clicking on the "Settings" and "URI Handling" then go to the link atom.io/packages/script, you will find the package and install it